# How to disable READ_XBUF caching?

Tags: g-wan

I am using this simple code.

```
#include "gwan.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
  xbuf_t *reply = get_reply(argv), *read_buff;

 read_buff = (xbuf_t*)get_env(argv, READ_XBUF);
 xbuf_cat(reply, "START\n"); xbuf_ncat(reply, read_buff->ptr, read_buff->len); xbuf_cat(reply, "END\n");

 // this line is important if I don't use read_buff everything seems OK
 // but I need parse read_buff :(
 printf("%s\n", read_buff->ptr); // this line is most important

return 200;
}
```

at first everything seems OK

shell:~$ for I in `seq 0 1`; do curl -A "" -H "TST: ${I}" 'http://test.com:8080/?read_buf.c&scp=3'; done

```
START
GET /?read_buf.cscp=3HTTP/1.1
Host: test.com8080
Accept: */*
TST: 0

END
START
GET /?read_buf.cscp=3HTTP/1.1
Host: test.com8080
Accept: */*
TST: 1

END
```

execute my loop again

```
START
GET /?read_buf.cscp=3HTTP/1.1
Host: test.com8080
Accept: */*
TST: 0

END
START
GET /?read_buf.cscp=3HTTP/1.1
Host: test.com8080
Accept: */*
TST: 1

END
```

execute my loop again

```
START
GET /?read_buf.cscp=3HTTP/1.1
Host: test.com8080
Accept: */*
TST: 0

END
START
GET /?read_buf.cscp=3HTTP/1.1
Host: test.com8080
Accept: */*
TST: 1

END
```

**but there is my problem. Where TST is still 0 ?**

execute my loop again

```
START
GET /?read_buf.cscp=3HTTP/1.1
Host: test.com8080
Accept: */*
TST: 0

END
START
GET /?read_buf.cscp=3HTTP/1.1
Host: test.com8080
Accept: */*
TST: 0

END
```

execute my loop again

```
START
GET /?read_buf.cscp=3HTTP/1.1
Host: test.com8080
Accept: */*
TST: 0

END
START
GET /?read_buf.cscp=3HTTP/1.1
Host: test.com8080
Accept: */*
TST: 0

END
```

**Why? Due to caching ? How to disable it?**

PS: The servlet was executing on G-WAN 4.3.14

Comment: BTW the time between each blocks is more than 200ms!!!

Comment: This is micro caching problem.

Comment: Caching is disabled by default, look at the `gwan/init.c` file.

Answer (score 0):

Since this question was posted **after** we replied to it by email, there is little doubt about its true objectives which are very far away from the alleged technical pretext.

To let people be judge, here is the reply we emailed that guy:

---

All users will see what your script is displaying.

And your script is not using any user-session. Under concurrency, this script displays the same information in the same manner for all clients.

G-WAN detects that, and this is triggering its cache because your script is slow (probably due to the print-to-console).

No such application would exist in the real world: you would use personalized URI parameters, or POST entities or even Cookies - something that your test carefully avoids - hence its irrelevance.

Besides, you might benefit from reading the G-WAN FAQs:

http://gwan.ch/faq#cache

Finally, G-WAN was not created to compete with any existing Web framework. The goal was merely to satisfy the needs of our own projects:

http://twd-industries.com/

And here G-WAN fits this task, very well, because we wrote it with the intent to use it properly.